# How to recycle app pool on a specific time during work days?

Tags: asp.net, iis

Is it possible to schedule an App Pool recycle on a specific time only during work days?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

In case you can't configure the desired schedule using IIS directly, you could create a scheduled task that invokes

```
c:\Windows\system32\inetsrv\appcmd.exe recycle apppool "NameOfTheAppPool"
```

at the required times.

Answer (score 4):

If you are using IIS 7, [`PeriodicRestart`](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add/recycling/periodicRestart) is the key.  Add the following into your `ApplicationHost.config` file:

```
<add name="YourApplicationPool">
   <recycling logEventOnRecycle="Schedule">
      <periodicRestart>
         <schedule>
            <clear />
            <add value="12:00:00" />
         </schedule>
      </periodicRestart>
   </recycling>
   <processModel identityType="NetworkService" shutdownTimeLimit="00:00:30" startupTimeLimit="00:00:30" />
</add>
```

It will recycle your `Application Pool` at 12 o'clock each day.

If you are using IIS7, you could setup a `Scheduled Task`, for the work days, running the following command:

`appcmd.exe recycle apppool "YourApplicationPool"`

If you are using IIS6, I'd follow the guide [here](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add/recycling#002).

Comment: how can we schedule to restart app pool something like once a week on once in a month on specific time each week or month accordingly. I do not want to restart app pools each day as it's too frequent.

Answer (score 2):

This [documentation](http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add/recycling) illustrates how to use app pool recycling settings.

```
<add name="Contoso">
   <recycling logEventOnRecycle="Schedule">
      <periodicRestart>
         <schedule>
            <clear />
            <add value="03:00:00" />
         </schedule>
      </periodicRestart>
   </recycling>
   <processModel identityType="NetworkService" shutdownTimeLimit="00:00:30" startupTimeLimit="00:00:30" />
</add>
```

Comment: But it does not enable to recycle the app pool only on weekdays. This can also not be achieved programmatically in IIS7. http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.applicationHost/applicationPools/add So the accepted answer is the only way.

Answer (score 0):

If you are hosting in Azure, you could use a [startup.cmd](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/cloud-services-startup-tasks/) file with the following (from [here](https://gist.github.com/biggyspender/3a534cffafef37f8231e)):

```
REM Prevent unwanted recycling
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.processModel.idleTimeout:00:00:00

%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:applicationPools -applicationPoolDefaults.recycling.periodicRestart.time:00:00:00

REM Recycle every day at 4am
%windir%\system32\inetsrv\appcmd set config -section:system.applicationHost/applicationPools /+applicationPoolDefaults.recycling.periodicRestart.schedule.[value='04:00:00'] /commit:apphost
```